# Form appear when a radio button selected

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-reactive-forms

**I want to display a form if a button (radio button ) is selected.**

So this is my form.ts :

```
lchartForm = this.fb.group({
  DataToload:[],
  firstname: [],
  lastname: []
 });
```

This is the component.html :

```
<form [formGroup]="lchartForm">

 <mat-radio-group aria-label="Select an option" formControlName="DataToload">
    <mat-radio-button value="Historics">Historics</mat-radio-button>
    <mat-radio-button value="Metrics" >Metrics</mat-radio-button>
  </mat-radio-group>

   <div *ngIf = "lchartForm.value['DataToload']==Historics" >

    <mat-form-field appearance="fill">
        <mat-label>first name</mat-label>
        <input matInput formControlName="firstname">
    </mat-form-field>
    <mat-form-field appearance="fill">
        <mat-label>last name</mat-label>
        <input matInput formControlName="lastname">
    </mat-form-field>
    </div>
```

But it gives me only the radio buttons ( the form of firstname and lastname doesn't appear).

Can anyone help me to fix this problem ?

Comment: Have you looked at console.log for errors The first things that pops out at me is that Historics is not in quotes.

Comment: Maybe this `lchartForm.value['DataToload']==Historics` should be `lchartForm.controls['DataToload'].value === 'Historics'`?

Comment: @R.Richards I got my problem ! the problem is the missing of quotes in Historics

Comment: @E.Maggini  Yes my problem is the missing of quotes, This is funny :p Thank you anyway :D

Comment: @foufaoueslati No worries. That is what pair programming is all about. Sometimes you stare at something for so long a blind spot develops. :)